Is a Riemannian submersion a harmonic map?
Is  every  Riemannian  submersion necessarily a Harmonic  map? If not under what  condition that is  true?
The motivation: the linear part of a Riemannian submersion is the direct sum og an isometry and the zero operator

I just realize that the answer is negative:

Radu Pantilie, Some remarks on harmonic Riemannian submersion, Bulletin mathématique de la Société des Sciences Mathématiques de Roumanie, Nouvelle Série Tome 40 (88), No. 1 (1997) pp. 21–26
https://www.jstor.org/stable/43678588


We give two conditions each one necessary and sufficient for a
Riemannian submersion to be harmonic. As an application, we show
how it can be modified the metric on the total space such that the
Riemannian submersion to become harmonic.


@DavidRoberts  I  appreciate  very much your  kind help  and  edit
